# RSA signing with AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rsa, signing, amazon-kms

I'm looking for a way to use aws-kms for ***RSA signing*** of arbitrary byte array. I was wondering if there is an API for that in aws-kms, or some building blocks that can be used together to build that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

KMS only generated symmetric data key and KMS key material is also symmetric. I believe it is not possible using KMS. Consider using [CloudHSM](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudhsm-jce-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/cloudhsm/examples/RSAOperationsRunner.java).